# Should the system of records be replicated to different system?

Tags: architecture, eai

I've a customer master system that's used for storing, updating and retrieving customer information. The service calls is of the order of 300-600 milliseconds. Obviously it's the system of records.

I'm designing another promotional system that would need customer master information. I'm wondering if the promotional system should make calls to customer master system every time it needs customer master information or should it keep a copy of database and try to synch up with the customer master system periodically?

Comment: Now you also have to take into account that replicating customer data to another system makes your infrastructure more difficult to comply with the GDPR regulations - if you deal with EU you need to consider also this :)

Answer (score 0):

With any replication method, there would be a chance of serving stale data. Hence it would depend if the application using the replicated SOR does get affected with the occasional stale data or not.

Also, I am not sure how big this customer data set is. Have you considered using a cache with LRU or a similar policy on it ?

Comment: Master data is huge running into a few millions. I haven't looked up caching. How is caching different from storing it in database?